# Is there any way to perform multithreading in flutter

Tags: multithreading, flutter, asynchronous

Documentation says flutter is single threaded even the asynchronous task is executed on the same thread which means that while we wait for another task to be completed, we will continue executing our synchronous code. But I have a situation where i need to process on multiple images, and process on each image takes approx 1.5 secconds. Sample code for this is below

```
for(var image in images){
    processOnImage(image);    
}

processOnImage(var image){
    // it takes approx 1.5 secconds 
}
```

So in above script if i have 20 images then it takes approx 30 seccond, which is too high in  my case.
So I want to know that is there any way to start multithreading to reduce time consumption, like below

```
for(var image in images){
    startNewThread processOnImage(image);    
}

processOnImage(var image){
    // it takes approx 1.5 secconds 
}
```

Comment: check `Isolate` class

Comment: Process image is happening online and you are awaiting an API or inside the app?

Comment: No its a ml task, now i am studying isolates because I think pskink answer is right

Comment: and if you dont want to play with low level `Isolate`s check top level global [compute()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute-constant.html) function

Comment: This blog might help you out - https://blog.logrocket.com/multithreading-flutter-using-dart-isolates/#:~:text=Flutter%20is%20a%20great%20framework,the%20form%20of%20a%20UI.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the dart docs.
https://dart.dev/guides/language/concurrency
**Dart supports concurrent programming**

```
for(var image in images){
    processOnImage(image);    
}

procesOnImage(var image){
    var receive = ReceivePort();
    Isolate.spawn(yourFunctionToRun, receive.sendPort);
}
```